# No sense in the expression $\hat{x}| 1\rangle=\sqrt{\frac{2}{a}}\int_{-\frac{a}{2}}^{\frac{a}{2}}x\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{a}x\right)dx=0$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, commutator, observables

I am considering a particle of mass *m* in a symmetric infinite square well of width *a*   in the fundamental state.

$$V(x)= \begin{cases} 0 & \mbox{$|x|<\frac{a}{2}$} \\ \infty  & \mbox{otherwise} \end{cases}$$

> I want to know what values are obtained from the measurement of energy $E$, position $x$ and impulse $p$ and the corresponding probabilities.

So I did:

$$\psi_{n=1}(x)=\sqrt{\frac{2}{a}}\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{a}x\right)$$
$$E_{1}=\frac{\hbar^2\pi^2}{2ma^2} \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\ P(E_1)=100\%$$
I can not calculate the eigenvalues of the operator position that I imagine is a continuous set of values in the interval $\left[ -\frac{a}{2},\frac{a}{2} \right]$.

Those that I have considered up until now are the eigenfunctions of the Hamiltonian and not of the position operator so I do not think it makes sense:

$$\hat{x}| 1\rangle=\sqrt{\frac{2}{a}}\int_{-\frac{a}{2}}^{\frac{a}{2}}x\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{a}x\right)dx=0$$
However I do not know how to do it or even for the momentum. 
I also have a suggestion that to calculate the probability of the momentum it is sufficient to calculate the wave function in the space of the impulses, but I honestly can not understand it

Comment: The equation in the title is wrong. The right-hand side is the expectation value, $\langle 1 | \hat{x} | 1 \rangle$, not $\hat{x} |1 \rangle$.

Comment: Is not $\langle 1| \hat{x} | 1\rangle =\frac{2}{a}\int_{-\frac{a}{2}}^{\frac{a}{2}}x\cos^2\left(\frac{\pi}{a}x\right)dx$

Comment: Oh yeah, you're right. The point is, what you have is not $\hat{x} |1 \rangle$ at all.

Comment: This is probably related to the content of the question

Comment: An operator acting on a state gets you a state, not a number.  If you wanted the expectation value, you would have to integrate *x cos^2(…)* and the answer would be zero by symmetry.

Comment: You claim to be trying to evaluate the eigenvalues of x but you are using the eigenstates of H, this is not even valid.  The eigenvalues of the operator x are x, the eigen functions are Dirac delta functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@knzhou already indicated the perfect appositeness of your title.

You apply the definitions of your text, as the chthonian pundit suggests,
$$\hat{x}| 1\rangle= \hat{x}\int dx ~|x\rangle\langle x| 1\rangle= \sqrt{\frac{2}{a}}\int_{-\frac{a}{2}}^{\frac{a}{2}}dx~~\left( x\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{a}      x\right)\right )  ~~~|x\rangle  . $$
The position operator just multiplies the wavefunction by *x* for every position *x*, but, of course, the state $|1\rangle$ is an *x* -integral of eigenstates of this operator with *x* -dependent coefficients, the very heart of Dirac's Bra-Ket formalism.

So, then,
$$\langle 1|\hat{x}| 1\rangle= \sqrt{\frac{2}{a}}\int_{-\frac{a}{2}}^{\frac{a}{2}}dx~~\left( x\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{a}      x\right)\right )  ~\langle 1|x\rangle   = \frac{2}{a} \int_{-\frac{a}{2}}^{\frac{a}{2}}dx~~\left( x\cos^2\left(\frac{\pi}{a}      x\right)\right )  =0  , $$
$\langle 1|\hat{x}^2| 1\rangle= a^2(1/12- 1/2\pi^2) $, etc.

You clearly naively calculated the eigenvalue of $\hat {p}^2$, since you have the eigenvalue of the energy; however, a [subtlety](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/232831/conservation-of-momentum-in-infinite-square-well)  prevents $|1\rangle$ from being an eigenstate of of $\hat p$, as the symmetric wave packet $\langle p|1\rangle$ is not infinitely sharp. In any case, you may avoid all this; confirm directly that $\langle 1| \hat{p}|1\rangle =0$, which might not be surprising; and, of course, $\langle 1| \hat{p}^2|1\rangle =\hbar^2\pi^2/a^2$. This is just 10% off saturating the uncertainty principle bound!

- Small footnote to be avoided until the fourth reading. The moot self-adjointness of this $\hat p$ is fully discussed in [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/362305/whats-the-deal-with-momentum-in-the-infinite-square-well).
- - Terms of use agreement, so in the smallest print possible, to only read with mental lawsuits in mind. In his book, Dirac defines $|x\rangle$ via the ''standard ket'' which, up to a normalization,  is but the translationally invariant momentum eigenstate $|\varpi\rangle=\lim_{p\to 0} |p\rangle$ in the momentum representation, i.e.,  $\hat{p}|\varpi\rangle=0$. Consequently, the corresponding wavefunction is a constant,  $\langle x|\varpi\rangle  \sqrt{2\pi \hbar}=1$. The definition is then $~~~|x\rangle= \delta(\hat{x}-x) |\varpi\rangle  \sqrt{2\pi \hbar}$.

Comment: Chthonian! Now that's something I've never been called before!

Comment: @knzhou misdirected adjective landing... I was reading the last comment.... will redress.

Comment: "You clearly calculated the eigenvalue of p^, since you have the eigenvalue of the energy, effectively its square, no? "
No. The momentum is ill defined in the infinite square well. The momentum operator is not self adjoint.

Comment: @ofthe... fair enough, but this is not the subtlety the OP is reaching for. The operatively word is "naively"...

Comment: Sorry maybe I did not understand your answer, but $\hat{x}| 1\rangle= \sqrt{\frac{2}{a}}\int_{-\frac{a}{2}}^{\frac{a}{2}}dx~~\left( x\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{a}      x\right)\right )  ~~~|x\rangle  = 0 |x \rangle $, hence the eigenvalue of p is only zero. And what about "those that I have considered up until now are the eigenfunctions of the Hamiltonian and not of the position operator"?Thank you very much for your availability.

Comment: Ach, Stefano, the integral is over both the function, *and* the labels of the eigenstates  |x> --they are part of the integrand too.  Think of the sum over all dummy *x*s  so  a sum over |x>s, each with its peculiar coefficient , the function in the big parenthesis. This is a formal integral you can't do to get a number. You get a sum of states.

Comment: Thank you, sorry for my little knowledge. But the probability of getting as a measure of position x is $|\langle x|1 \rangle|^2 $? Is it correct? Just to understand if I understood

Comment: You are right. So, in the last expression, you have $\int dx ~~ x~~ |\langle x|1\rangle|^2$.