# Is it possible to calculate the average value of $x^{2}p^{2}$ for an infinite square well?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

If you can only measure either position and momentum in quantum mechanics how would one find the average value of $x^{2}p^{2}$ for an infinite square well?

Comment: It does not make sense: that operstor is not selfadjoint so it is not an observable.

Comment: [Related](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/362305/whats-the-deal-with-momentum-in-the-infinite-square-well), and [also](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/232831/conservation-of-momentum-in-infinite-square-well).

Comment: Before going on, what's the point of your question? It has a whiff of an intermediate step for something, but what? Have you brushed up on the [pitfalls](https://aapt.scitation.org/doi/10.1119/1.4864740) of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for can indeed be found. It is simply $\int\psi^*(x)\ \left(-x^2\hbar^2\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}\right)\psi(x)dx$. Substitute whichever state of the infinite square well you like and work out the integral.

The problem is that this is a different result from say $p^2x^2$ or $xpxp$ because the order of $x$ and $p$ cannot be swapped.

Comment: You've made a typo. I don't think this is correct.