# Is the momentum in the infinite square well observable or not?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, wavefunction, momentum, boundary-conditions

I've read in posts such as [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/232831/) and [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/52768/) that the momentum operator is not self-adjoint in the infinite square well because the geometric space is a bounded region of $\mathbb R$, for example $[0,a]$ for a well of width $a$. As such, it leads to weird stuff happening like momentum not being conserved.

What I don't understand is why the domain of the wave functions cannot be extended to $\mathbb R$ and have $\psi$ simply equal $0$ outside the well. That way, instead of integrating from $0$ to $a$, we can integrate from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$. Then
$$
\langle \psi | \hat p \psi \rangle = \frac{\hbar}{i}\psi^*\psi \bigg\rvert_{-\infty}^{+\infty} + \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \left(\frac{\hbar}{i} \frac{\mathrm d \psi}{\mathrm dx} \right)^* \psi \; \mathrm dx = \langle \hat p \psi | \psi\rangle,
$$
and $\hat p$ would still be self-adjoint. Also, does the boundary condition for the stationary states $\psi(0) = \psi(a) = 0$ not predicate on the assumption that $\psi = 0$ outside the well? If $\psi$ was not defined outside the well, $\psi$ does not have to be continuous at the walls of the well, so $\psi(0)$ and $\psi(a)$ could equal any value.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/362305/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/66429/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/45498/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Why would momentum be conserved in this system? That doesn't seem weird at all to me.

Comment: For anyone learning quantum mechanics and puzzled by this issue: don't worry, in a finite well the ordinary momentum operator is perfectly ok and you can always apply the ideas of standard quantum theory to a finite but very deep well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not necessary to extend the wavefunctions to the whole real line. As far as I can understand, you are defining an operator $\hat{p}$ in $L^2([0,a], dx)$ with the domain $D(\hat{p}) := \{ \psi\in C^1([0,a])\:|\: \psi(a) = \psi(0)=0\}$ and acting in that way
$$(\hat{p}\psi)(x):= -i\hbar \psi'(x)\:.$$
As you notice, that operator is Hermitian. However, in QM observables need to be **selfadjoint** operators, which is a much stronger requirement.
Selfadjoint operators admit a spectral decomposition, simply hermitian ones do not.

From a mathematical perspective, posts you found yourself and other [posts](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/362305/whats-the-deal-with-momentum-in-the-infinite-square-well) indicated by Qmechanic focus on related issues. In particular, if candidate momentum operators defined as above or in a similar way (with Dirichlet boundary conditions) admit a unique selfadjoint extension. The answer is negative. There is no good *momentum observable* in an infinite square well (i.e., with vanishing boundary conditions).