# On the infinite potential well: an apparent paradox

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, momentum, schroedinger-equation, commutator

$$
V(x) = \left\{
\begin{split}
0&\quad \operatorname{in}\ [0, a] \\
+\infty&\quad \operatorname{elsewhere}
\end{split}
\qquad  a>0,
\right.
$$

The Schrödinger equation for stationary states on the interval $[0, a]$,
$$
-{\hbar}^2\frac{{\mathrm{d}}^2}{{\mathrm{d}}x^2} \psi(x) = E\psi(x),
$$
with boundary conditions $\psi(0)=\psi(a)=0$ has solutions
$$
\psi_n(x) = \sqrt{\frac{2}{a}}\sin\left(k_n x\right) \qquad \text{with eigenvalues} \qquad E_n=\frac{\hbar^2 k_n^2}{2m}
$$
and $\displaystyle k_n=\frac{n\pi}{a}$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Here's the **paradox**: in what follows 1. and 2. **should not hold together**, **but they do**.

1.**The energy eigenstates are not momentum eigenstates**:
$$
-i\hbar\frac{{\rm{d}}}{{\rm{d}}x}\psi_n(x)=-i\hbar k_n\sqrt{\frac{2}{a}}\cos(k_nx) \; \not\propto\; \psi_n(x)
$$
2. In this case, **energy and momentum commute**.
Here's a quick proof by [user115625](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/115625/user115625):

> \begin{equation}
> [\hat H, \hat p] = [\hat T+ V, \hat p]
> =[\dfrac{\hat p^2}{2m}+ V, \hat p]
> =[\dfrac{\hat p^2}{2m}, \hat p] + [V, \hat p]
> \end{equation}
> Note that here, in general, the potential is a function of $\hat x$, i.e. $V(x)$. Using the property of commutators
> $$[AB, C] =A[B,C]+[A,C]B$$
> and the result that for any function $f$
> $$[f, \hat p]=i \hbar \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}$$
> we get
> $$
> [\hat H, \hat p]=\dfrac{1}{2m}(\hat p[\hat p,\hat p]+[\hat p,\hat p]\hat p)+i \hbar \dfrac{\partial V}{\partial x}= i \hbar \dfrac{\partial V}{\partial x}
> $$
> Therefore
> \begin{equation}
> \boxed{\dfrac{\partial V}{\partial x}=0 \implies [\hat H, \hat p] = 0}
> \end{equation}

Comment: This excellent question touches on an important area often under-emphasized in quantum mechanics classes: boundary conditions. The momentum operator commutes with the Hamiltonian everywhere *inside* the well, but not at the edges, nor outside the well.

Comment: Ok but since solutions can only be found inside it, who cares about what happens outside?

Comment: Relevant question and links therein: [link](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/696618/).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the deal with momentum in the infinite square well?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/362305/)

Comment: The "commutator stuff" at point 2 is meaningless, since the operators are not defined, the domain of the commutator is not defined, etc.

Comment: *"who cares about what happens outside?"* Well, you should. What I'm trying to tell you is that $[H, p] \neq 0$ because of the boundary points.