# Can I use Heisenberg picture to derive energy levels of a 1D infinite quantum well?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, potential, schroedinger-equation, hamiltonian

Can I use the [Heisenberg picture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_picture) to derive energy levels of a 1D infinite quantum well?

I know how this goes with the [Schrödinger picture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_picture), and to follow the same procedure, it seems I must separate variables of some sort of a motion equation?

Comment: It is a time-independent problem, whereas Schrödinger vs. Heisenberg picture deal with how one treats time dependence.

Comment: You obviously mean "matrix versus wave mechanics", not Heisenberg picture, which means something else altogether in time-dependence implementation. The matrix mechanics picture actually furnishes [celebrated conceptual advantages](https://doi.org/10.1119/1.4864740). Read up!

Comment: @RogerVadim Surely I agree with your opinion, and I think Cosmas Zachos has gave exactly the reference I need.

Comment: @CosmasZachos Much thanks, that's really nice of you.

Comment: [Linked](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/412564/66086).